# Member function [c++] definition not found by VS2015 due to #define

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Have a #define which is called within a member function. By this #define the member-function definition isn't found by the VS2015 environment at the declaration level. The project compiles and runs just fine so no problem there.

This does however, break the functionality of VS2015 to jump between the declaration and definition.

It can be solved by writing the #define within the source, but can this be solved without removing the #define?

**File: cFoo.h**

```
class cFoo
{
public:
    int Bits;
    void Member();
}
```

**File: cFoo.cpp**

```
#include "cFoo.h"

#define SWITCH( x ) for ( int bit = 1; x >= bit; bit *= 2) if (x & bit) switch (bit)

void cFoo::Member()
{
    SWITCH( Bits )
    {
    case 1: break;
    case 2: break;
    default: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: A #define is a "preprocessor macro", not a function, so it isn't called, it is textually expanded.  I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but VS Intellisense doesn't really do well "looking in" to macro expansions; there are lots of limitations.  E.g., can't use them in watch windows, can't search for the code that they expand into, etc.

Comment: This snippet just cycles through every bit in a bitwise integer and executes the case.

Comment: *This does however, break the functionality of VS2015 to jump between the declaration and definition.* Declaration and definition of what? The member function? That is strange if true.

Comment: Indeed, the member-function. Probably due to the define ends with switch(bit) and there is no scope in the #define. That's followed in the function definition.

Comment: @davidbak If a #define isn't called, how should I mention it then? (Ofcourse the code is filled in at compile time)

Comment: In your macro where is the identifier - parameter `s32` defined?

Comment: In a third-party library: `typedef __int32 s32;` Will edit it here to just `int`.

Comment: kk just needed to know to test your macro.

Comment: My deepest apologies.

Comment: @Tim - I'm sorry but I don't really know what you mean "how should I mention it".  It seems to me, based on your language, that the root of your problem is expecting macros to behave, in the IDE, like functions.  They don't.  The reasons are probably historical (that is, in the history of IDE development) combined with lack of interest in fixing the problem as macros are not considered good programming style so not worth the effort.  But if you could explain what you mean by "how should I mention it" ... maybe we could unravel the mystery here.

Comment: as a side note, check out std::bitset<> for your bit manipulating needs

Comment: @davidbak: You said a #define isn't called. Therefor how should I refer to it then. What I expect a define is/can be: It is just a name, then whatever follows it. In this case it is just a peace of code fitted in a reference-name and when the compiler encouters the reference-name, it fills in the text after a #define. Much like a #using "file". Ofcourse there are several uses for #define. Just don't know how I should mention a 'call' to a #define other then 'call'.

Comment: It is common to refer to macro "call" as [macro expansion](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Macro-Expansion.html). In this particular case it would be a good idea to replace macro with a template function accepting callable object.

Comment: Or it is just called a "use".

Comment: @VTT std::bitset seems to be a template you mean. It seems that would make life easier indeed.

Comment: The point is, macros are a language feature orthogonal to functions.  In fact, they were initially implemented with a completely separate processor - not the compiler (though packaged with the compiler in a runnable wrapper).  So the language used to talk about them is not the same, and in particular, they don't really have the same concept of "definition" and "declaration" as far as the IDE is concerned; the IDE won't generally look into them (for searches and such) and, critically, definitions and uses don't usually appear in the symbol tables that are used in the debugger.  They're limited.

Comment: No, I mean using a template function instead of macro, regardless of `std::bitset` use. This function will iterate over set bits and invoke a callable object for each set bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would disadvice to use such constructs. It is rather counterintuitive and difficult to understand.

Possible problems/difficulties:

- switch case with breaks suggests that only one case is executed, but your macro logic hides the loop.
- the default case is executed multiple times depending on the highest populated bit.
- using `signed int` as bit set -> use `unsigned` - its less prone to implementation defined behavior
- it is possibly slow because of loop (I do not know if the compiler is able to unroll and optimize it)
- its called `SWITCH_BITS` which suggests that bit numbers are expected, but cases have to be powers of two.

Your whole statement is not more compact than a simple `if` sequence.

```
if(bits & 1 ){
}
if(bits & 1024){
}
```

but you maybe want to test to bit numbers:

```
inline bool isBitSet(u32 i_bitset, u32 i_bit){ return i_bitset & (1 << i_bit);}

if(isBitSet(bits, 0){
}
if(isBitSet(bits, 10){
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try doing this by completing the switch statement within the `#define` - `macro`:

**Foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#ifndef SWITCH
    #define SWITCH(x)                                   \
        do {                                            \
            for ( int bit = 1; (x) >= bit; bit *=2 ) {  \
                if ( (x) & bit ) {                      \
                    switch( bit ) {                     \
                         case 0: break;                 \
                         case 1: break;                 \
                         default: break;                \
                     }                                  \
                }                                       \
            }                                           \
        } while(0)
#endif

class Foo {
public:
    int Bits;
    void Member();
};

#endif // !FOO_H
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.h"

void Foo::Member() {
    SWITCH( this->Bits );
}
```

When I was trying the `#define` or `macro` as you had it, `Foo::Member()`
was not being defined by intellisense...

However even with it not being defined I was able to build, compile and run it like this:

```
#ifndef SWITCH_A
    #define SWITCH_A(x)                             \
        for ( int bit = 1; (x) >= bit; bit *= 2 )   \
            if ( (x) & bit )                        \
                switch (bit) 
#endif
```

For some reason; MS Visual Studio was being very picky with it; meaning that I was having a hard time getting it to compile; it was even complaining about the "spacing" giving me compiler errors of `missing {` or `; need before...` etc. Once I got all the spacing down properly it did eventually compile & run, but intellisense was not able to see that `Foo::Member()` was defined. When I tried it in the original manner that I've shown above; intellisense had no problem seeing that `Foo::Member()` was defined. Don't know if it's a pre-compiler bug, MS Visual Studio bug etc.; Just hope that this helps you.

Comment: +1 for the direct answer of the actual question. Digesting the matter of vlad_tepesch due to usability of his answer.